# Can composer be used without php phar support?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm trying to deploy a **Symfony 2** app on a dedicated managed server, and i'm using **composer** to download my own bundles which hosted on a private **Packagist** instance of my company, plus of course the other public bundles from **Packagist.org** .

The hosting company of the server disabled **php phar** support by default -they say for security reasons !-, and it take some time on the support tickets to make them enable it, in order to initially deploy my app, moreover they asked me to notify them whenever i finish deployment so they can disable it again.

In case we need to make more deployments as we maintain future releases, is there a way to use **composer** to deploy the app without **php phar** support ?

Comment: Yes, Build it all locally, then test all is correct, then FTP the tested code to the live server like normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, out of the box **composer** cannot be used on a server with phar-support disabled.

However, **composer** has a command archive which will let you build an archive of your project which you can easily use to deploy your app. Just build it locally and publish your archive on the distant server.

---

Last possibility, (never tested). Composer is a php project as any other. Perhaps, if you clone the repo and try to run it as a plain php commande, it might actually work.

```
git clone git@github.com:composer/composer.git
php bin/composer
```

Comment: @i-am-michiel what do you mean by building an archive for my project?
what is an archive and how it is deployed ?

Comment: By default, it generates a zip file of your project. You can simply upload that file and unzip the archive. It will contains all vendors.